# Polynomial Congruence Question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: Bottom of page 73 in George Andrews' Number Theory, Dover Edition]

I'm working on #4. #3 seemed pretty straightforward.

Using #3, the problem becomes showing that $f(m) + rp^s f'(m) \equiv 0\mod p^{s+1}$

Since $f(m) \equiv 0\mod p^s$, $f(m) = np^s$ for some integer n. (I know this is not the way but this is where my brain went.)

Then I have $np^s + rp^s f'(m) = p^s (n + rf'(m))$

For this to be congruent to $0\mod p^{s+1}$, then $n + rf'(m) \equiv 0\mod p^{s+1}$.

So $r \equiv -n[f'(m)]^{-1} \mod p^{s+1}$.

Is there something salvageable in this? I'm studying on my own and have no advisor/professor to talk to.

Comment: Thanks for formatting your work!  In the future, given your handle on mathjax, please consider typing out/formattin the questions you ask, rather than posting an image of it.  Links to images fail over time, and we like to keep questions and answers in an archive.

Comment: Search on "Hensel" here to find proofs and related results.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but for the congruence
$$p^s(n+rf'(m))\equiv0\pmod{p^{s+1}},$$
to hold, it suffices that
$$n+rf'(m)\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$
Now use the fact that $p$ does not divide $f'(m)$ to find an expression for $r$, as you already did.

Comment: Is my expression correct? Since p does not divide f'(m), there is some remainder mod p. Since p is prime, this remainder has an  inverse.

Comment: That is the right idea, and it shows that $r$ is unique modulo $p$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did some digging and found out this theorem has a name. Problem 5 in this  book asks to find a solution to a specific polynomial congruence using this lemma. I was able to use this link to find a solution: http://math453spring2009.wikidot.com/hensel-s-lemma